# SBJson int parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, int

I have a json string:

```
{"1":{"homeTeam":"Home01","awayTeam":"Away01","homeScore":0,"awayScore":0,"gameID":1},"2":{"homeTeam":"Home11","awayTeam":"Away11","homeScore":0,"awayScore":0,"gameID":2},"3":{"homeTeam":"Home21","awayTeam":"Away21","homeScore":0,"awayScore":0,"gameID":3}}
```

that I would like to turn into an Objective-C class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface ScoreKeeperGame : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *homeTeam;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *awayTeam;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int homeScore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int awayScore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int gameID;

- (id) init: (NSString *) homeTeam 
   awayTeam: (NSString *) awayTeam;

- (id) init: (NSDictionary *) game;

@end
```

I pass the json in by NSDictionary "game" (the json string represents a hashmap, so the first game is):

```
{"homeTeam":"Home01","awayTeam":"Away01","homeScore":0,"awayScore":0,"gameID":1}
```

When I try to use this class:

```
#import "ScoreKeeperGame.h"


@implementation ScoreKeeperGame
@synthesize homeTeam=_homeTeam, awayTeam = _awayTeam, homeScore = _homeScore, awayScore     = _awayScore, gameID = _gameID;

- (id) init: (NSString *) homeTeam 
   awayTeam: (NSString *) awayTeam
{
    self = [super init];
    self.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    self.awayTeam = awayTeam;

NSLog(@"away: %@", awayTeam);
return self;
}

- (id) init: (NSDictionary *) game
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
    self.homeTeam = [game objectForKey:@"homeTeam"];
    self.awayTeam = [game objectForKey:@"awayTeam"];
    self.awayScore = (int) [game objectForKey:@"awayScore"];
    self.gameID = [game objectForKey:@"gameID"];

    NSLog(@"game awayScore: %d", self.awayScore);
    NSLog(@"game gameID: %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.gameID]);
    }
return self;
}

@end
```

The awayScore and gameId are printed as large numbers (maybe pointers)?

I've tried

```
self.awayScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [game objectForKey:@"awayScore"]];
```

But that didn't seem to work either.

How do I get the value of the int from the game object?

`po game` produces:

```
{
awayScore = 0;
awayTeam = Away01;
gameID = 1;
homeScore = 0;
homeTeam = Home01;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pull it out as an NSNumber first.

```
NSNumber *myNum = [game objectForKey:@"awayScore"];

self.awayScore = [myNum intValue];
```

Doh!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you want to get integer value from your JSON response

```
self.awayScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[game objectForKey:@"awayScore"] intValue]];
```

as your response would be in nsstring.

Answer (score 0):

iOs 6.0, now it's simply [game[@"awayScore"] intValue]